# switch locations in google map api 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have a Map with custom style and its working great,
I was wondering if I can somehow control the location of the map using some links in my page, 
suppose I have 2 locations, I want to have

```
<a href="#" id="locaation1">Location1</a>
```

&

```
<a href="#" id="locaation2">Location2</a>
```

Then when I click on Location 1 map goes to that location , and same story for location 2, is it possible with jquery?
It would also be great if I can add a custom marker to each location too.
Thanks.

Comment: need to show your map initialize code to be able to add marker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can even do it without jquery,  the panto method is what you want to use, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map  basically,  just add a call to a predefined function into your anchor onclick event (or use a click handler in jquery to wire it up).

using jquery, you would need something like:

```
$("#location1").click(function(){
   var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922),
   g_map.panTo(pos);  //reference to globally defined google maps object
});
```

Here is a simple example from the google api documentation that can easily be retrofitted using the hints I have provided above:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-simple

Comment: Thanks, Exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

if your instance of map is named "map", you can use:

`<a href="#" onclick="map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long))" id="location1">Location1</a>`